# MySQL Query limit 3 or more if last 3 are equal?

Tags: mysql

I need to limit my result to 3 row (an example), but if 3rd result is equal to 4th, print also 4th, and so on.
To explain: from this table

```
id         punteggio
1          100
2          200
3          70
4          100
5          54
6          201
7          200
```

if I do

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY punteggio DESC LIMIT 3
```

i need in every case to print following situation:

```
id         punteggio
6           201
2           200
7           200
1           100
4           100
```

Because my "three" best points are in reality 5 of 7, cause 2 and 7 have same points, like 1 and 4...

I dont'know in advance min and max points, otherwise i would do

```
"WHERE punteggio >= 100"
```

Thank you very much!

UPDATE

Unfortunately my scenario changed:

punteggio born from SUM from another table:

```
id          idPersona              punteggio
1             1                        30
2             1                        -10
3             2                        50
4             3                        60
5             2                        -10
6             3                        150
7             1                        190
```

and so on...

i've tried do:

```
SELECT  persone.nome,
SUM(transazioni.importoFinale) AS punti
FROM    transazioni
INNER JOIN persone ON persone.idPersona = transazioni.idPersona
INNER JOIN 

(SELECT DISTINCT(SUM(transazioni.importoFinale)) AS punti,
persone.nome
FROM    transazioni
INNER JOIN persone on persone.idPersona = transazioni.idPersona
GROUP BY persone.idPersona
ORDER BY punti DESC
LIMIT 3) subq ON transazioni.punti = subq.punti
ORDER BY punti DESC
```

but it doens't function...

Thank you to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery join to get the `DISTINCT` set of 3 greatest values for `punteggio` and join it against the main table to retrieve all rows that have those values.

```
SELECT
  id,
  punteggio
FROM
  yourtable
  /* subquery gets the top 3 values only */
  /* and the INNER JOIN matches it to all rows in the main table having those values */
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT punteggio as p
     FROM yourtable
     ORDER BY punteggio DESC
     LIMIT 3
  ) subq ON yourtable.punteggio = subq.p
ORDER BY punteggio DESC
```

#### [Here's a demo on SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/808e8/4)

Comment: Both solution are perfect! Thank you to both!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, punteggio
FROM yourtable
WHERE punteggio IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT punteggio
       FROM yourtable
       ORDER BY punteggio DESC
       LIMIT 3
   ) AS temp
);
```

Note that the `select *` is present to work around mysql not supporting limits in subqueries in an `IN()` clause.

Comment: Both solution are perfect! Thank you to both!